# Cancel Video Conversion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto, powerpoint

I have developed a PowerPoint addin that converts the currently open presentation to a .wmv file.

It all works nicely. When the presentation is converting I can see a progress bar at the bottom of PowerPoint along with a red X which can be pressed to cancel the conversion process.

Is there a way of programmatically calling this cancel button some how?

This is the code I use to call it and wait for it to finish but I would also like to be able to cancel it while it's in progress.

```
private void frmUpload_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            progressBarUpload.Value = 0;
            string exportName = "video_of_presentation";
            string exportPath = @"C:\Windows\Temp\{0}.wmv";

            // Export the currently open presentation
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application ppApplication = null;
            ppApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
            ppApplication.Activate();
            ppApplication.ActivePresentation.SaveAs(String.Format(exportPath, exportName), Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsWMV);
            lblUploadStatus.Text = "Status: Converting …";

            new Thread(() =>
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
                /* run your code here */
                do
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

                }
                while (ppApplication.ActivePresentation.CreateVideoStatus != Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpMediaTaskStatus.ppMediaTaskStatusDone);

                backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

                SetControlPropertyValue(lblUploadStatus, "text", "Status: Uploading …");

            }).Start();
        }
        catch
        {
            lblUploadStatus.Text = "Status: Error Converting File.";
        }
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Trev

Answer (score 0):

According to MSFT this is not possible :(

Thread is here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9308ca45-ec8e-42df-8a5f-a150468a6213/cancel-microsoftofficeinteroppowerpointppsaveasfiletype

Trev